# Datetimepicker returns the date as a datetime format instead of timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datetimepicker

I'm using the datetimepicker js script and have the following logic implemented:

```
<script>
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate();
            var mm = today.getMonth();
            var yy = today.getFullYear();
            var hh = today.getHours();
            var now = new Date();
            now.setHours(now.getHours() + 2);
            var isPM = now.getHours() >= 12;
            var isMidday = now.getHours() == 12;
            var result = document.querySelector('#result');
            var time = [now.getHours() - (isPM && !isMidday ? 12 : 0),
                now.getMinutes()].join(':') +
                    (isPM ? ' pm' : 'am');

            var logic = function (currentDateTime) {
                if (currentDateTime.getDate() == dd && currentDateTime.getFullYear() == yy && currentDateTime.getMonth() == mm) {

                    this.setOptions({
                        formatTime: 'g:i A',
                        format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
                        minDate: '+1970/01/02', //or 1986/12/08,
                        minTime: time
                    });
                } else
                    this.setOptions({
                        formatTime: 'g:i A',
                        format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
                        minDate: '+1970/01/02', //or 1986/12/08,
                        minTime: '0:00 AM'
                    });
            };


            jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                onChangeDateTime: logic,
                onShow: logic
            });

        </script>
```

and now my dateTimepicker looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/BemGm.png .

But when I choose some date and time later on (using `var date = $("#datetimepicker").val();`) in return I have the format `30/06/2015 02:04 PM`, but I would like to have a timestamp instead. How can I convert it to the timestamp then?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this:

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker("getDate").getTime()/1000
```

This should return it in your desired time format.

Comment: Thanks, should I add it in my `var date=`... here? or in the script itself?

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't get it. :-D Which `var date=` do you mean? haven't found it in your code. I would use it at the place where you try to receive the time and need the conversion.

Comment: Later on in the code on my webpage I use the results from datetimepicker by writing `var date = $("#datetimepicker").val();` and so far the when I print `date` I see the date in a format `30/06/2015 02:04 PM` and instead I would like to have a timestamp there. So maybe there's a way to convert it on that point of the code?

Comment: hey, sorry if it's stupid problem, I just don't know exactly how to use it at this point, line `var date = $("#datetimepicker").getDate().getTime().val();` doesn't work :( Could you give me some example of how to convert the datetime to timestamp at this point?

Comment: Remove the `.val() `at the end. This should do the trick. `.val()` expects a jQuery object, which isn't returned by `getTime()`.